# How to change default title of errorSummary from "Errors" to something else in EXTJs

Tags: extjs

How to customize errorSummary in Extjs? The default title for errorSummary is "Errors"(screenshot attached for reference), is there any way to change it to something else?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcjhM.png)

```
 Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
 storeId:'simpsonsStore',
 fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
 data: [
     {"name":"Lisa", "email":"lisa@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-111-1224"},
     {"name":"Bart", "email":"bart@simpsons.com", "phone":"555--222-1234"},
     {"name":"Homer", "email":"home@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1244"},
     {"name":"Marge", "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"}
 ] 
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
title: 'Simpsons',
store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
columns: [
    {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
    {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank: false
        }
    },
    {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'}
],
selType: 'rowmodel',
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        errorSummary:true,
    })
],
height: 200,
width: 400,
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        errorsText:'test',
        errorSummary:true
    })
],
```

Comment: @JojoRaghav please mark as correct answer if its working

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change it globally,We  can override the editing plugin by using below code.

```
     Ext.define('OverridedRowEditing',{
       override: 'Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing',
       config: {
           errorsText: 'Test'
       }
    });
```